# matlab2tikz logo

Tags: matlab2tikz, logos

As the author of the free and open-source package [matlab2tikz](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22022-matlab2tikz), I was going to create a nice-looking logo for the software that is easily recognized on [MATLAB's file exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/index?sort=downloads_desc&term=) and representative of matlab2tikz' capabilities.

Any ideas for combining MATLAB with the awesomeness of LaTeX in one iconic figure?

Comment: Great idea. I like it.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This is courtesy of my friend [Ariel](http://www.arieldesign.de):

[image]

And its evolution and variations:
[image]

Comment: Simple, clean and professional!

Comment: Where is the source code? What was the tool used to generate such beautiful logo?

Comment: There is no source code. It is manual and conceptual work and Photoshop. @Nico I can provide high resolution images, just contact me.

Comment: All shapes are quite straight here so I guess given the images here any tracing tool could produce a reasonably good SVG representation.

Answer (score 31):

My little contribution to a great package which helped me lot of times. I am grateful to @Nico.

Scroll down for various versions.

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=0pt,dvipsnames]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations, decorations.text,shadows}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw=white,line width=4pt,rounded corners = 10pt,fill=Orange!20,anchor=south west,inner sep=-1pt,outer sep=0pt] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=4cm]{Matlab-Logo}};
    \begin{scope}[
        x={(image.south east)},
        y={(image.north west)}
    ]        
        \path[anchor=west, postaction={
                    decoration={raise=.37ex,
                    text along path,
                    text format delimiters={|}{|},
                    text={%
                            |\bfseries\footnotesize\color{red!70!black}|
                            matlab2tikz
                        },
                        text align=center,
                        reverse path
                    },
                    decorate
                }
            ]
              (0.55,0.85) arc (80:180:1.5cm); % (0,.45) -- (.6,.88);
        \path[line cap = round,color = OliveGreen,-latex, line width=2] (0.6,0.6) edge[bend left=28,opacity = .7] (0.8,0.18);
        \node[draw=Goldenrod!50!red,double,fill=olive!20,drop shadow] at (0.8,0.095) {Ti\textit{\color{orange}k}Z};
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

`Matlab-Logo` is from [http://commons.wikimedia.org/](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Matlab_Logo.png)

## Version -2

<sub>I am not a lawyer and hence have no idea if I am making mathworks angry !!!</sub>

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=0pt,dvipsnames]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations, decorations.text,shadows}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw=white,line width=4pt,rounded corners = 10pt,fill=Orange!20,anchor=south west,inner sep=-1pt,outer sep=0pt] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=4cm,angle=90]{Matlab-Logo}}; %% Matlab-Logo  or  membrane1
    \begin{scope}[
        x={(image.south east)},
        y={(image.north west)}
    ]
        \path[anchor=west, postaction={
                    decoration={raise=.37ex,
                    text along path,
                    text format delimiters={|}{|},
                    text={%
                            |\bfseries\footnotesize\color{red!70!black}|
                            matlab2tikz
                        },
                        text align=center,
                        reverse path
                    },
                    decorate
                }
            ]
              (0.75,0.9) arc (80:140:3cm); % (0,.45) -- (.6,.88);        
        \node[draw=Goldenrod!50!red,double,fill=olive!20,drop shadow,anchor=south](tikz) at (0.37,0.095) {\Huge Ti\textit{\color{orange}k}Z};
        \path[line cap = round,color = OliveGreen,-latex, line width=2] (0.72,0.75) edge[in=0, out =0,opacity = 1] (tikz.east);
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

## Version - 3

<sub>Let us not annoy mathworks ;-)</sub>

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=0pt,dvipsnames]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations, decorations.text,shadows}    
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw=white,line width=4pt,rounded corners = 10pt,fill=Orange!20,anchor=south west,inner sep=-1pt,outer sep=0pt] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=4cm]{logo2}}; %% Matlab-Logo  or  membrane1
    \begin{scope}[
        x={(image.south east)},
        y={(image.north west)}
    ]
        \path[anchor=west, postaction={
                    decoration={raise=.37ex,
                    text along path,
                    text format delimiters={|}{|},
                    text={%
                            |\bfseries\footnotesize\color{red!70!black}|
                            matlab2tikz
                        },
                        text align=center,
                        reverse path
                    },
                    decorate
                }
            ]
              (0.55,0.85) arc (80:180:1.5cm); % (0,.45) -- (.6,.88);        
        \node[draw=Goldenrod!50!red,double,fill=olive!20,drop shadow,anchor=south] (tikz) at (0.8,0.045) {\LARGE Ti\textit{\color{orange}k}Z};
        \node[draw=Blue!50!red,double,fill=blue!10,anchor=south] (matlab) at (0.2,0.25) {\fontsize{3}{4}\selectfont\scshape Matlab};
        \path[line cap = rect,color = Red!80!green,-latex, line width=1] (matlab.east) edge[out=0,in=180,opacity = 1] (tikz.west);
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And the `logo2` -- `membrane` plotted in matlab:

[image]

and the matlab code:

```
L = membrane; 
s = surf(L) , view(-52,30), axis off; colormap('cool');
camlight; shading interp;
set(s, 'facelighting', 'phong', 'facealpha', 0.9);
```

## version - 4

<sub>Nico wants LaTeX to appear and I don't want to drop TikZ ;-)</sub>

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=0pt,dvipsnames]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations, decorations.text,shadows}
\usepackage{palatino}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw=white,line width=4pt,rounded corners = 10pt,fill=Orange!20,anchor=south west,inner sep=-1pt,outer sep=0pt] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=4cm]{logo3}}; %% Matlab-Logo  or  membrane1
    \begin{scope}[
        x={(image.south east)},
        y={(image.north west)}
    ]
        \node[text width= 4cm,align=center,opacity=.15,color=Orange!20] at (0.5,0.5){
        \LaTeX\ \LaTeX\ \LaTeX\ \LaTeX\ \LaTeX\ \LaTeX
        \LaTeX\ \LaTeX\ \LaTeX\ \LaTeX\ \LaTeX\ \LaTeX
        \LaTeX\ \LaTeX\ \LaTeX\ \LaTeX\ \LaTeX\ \LaTeX
        \LaTeX\ \LaTeX\ \LaTeX\ \LaTeX\ };
        \path[anchor=west, postaction={
                    decoration={raise=.37ex,
                    text along path,
                    text format delimiters={|}{|},
                    text={%
                            |\bfseries\footnotesize\color{red!70!black}|
                            matlab2tikz
                        },
                        text align=center,
                        reverse path
                    },
                    decorate
                }
            ]
              (0.55,0.85) arc (80:180:1.5cm); % (0,.45) -- (.6,.88);
        \node[draw=Goldenrod!50!red,double,fill=olive!20,drop shadow,anchor=south] (tikz) at (0.8,0.045) {\LARGE Ti\textit{\color{orange}k}Z};
        \node[draw=Blue!50!red,double,fill=blue!10,anchor=south] (matlab) at (0.2,0.25) {\fontsize{3}{4}\selectfont\scshape Matlab};
        \path[line cap = rect,color = Red!80!green,-latex, line width=1] (matlab.east) edge[out=0,in=180,opacity = 1]node[midway,sloped,color=white,scale=0.6,transform shape]{\fontsize{3}{4}\selectfont \raisebox{-1.8ex}{{\large{2}}}} (tikz.west);
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Play around by putting

```
\node[draw=Goldenrod!50!red,double,fill=olive!20,drop shadow,anchor=south] (tikz) at (0.8,0.045) {\LARGE .tikz};
\node[draw=Blue!50!red,double,fill=blue!10,anchor=south] (matlab) at (0.2,0.25) {\fontsize{3}{4}\selectfont .fig};
```

to indicate the conversion.

Comment: Dear downvoter, Thank you for the downvote. Kindly suggest improvements through a comment besides downvoting.

Comment: Nice! Just a minor detail; perhaps you could modify the code so that the color in the region where the green arrow body meets the arrow tip has the same shade as the rest of the arrow? Currently there is a darker little region there.

Comment: I'm not sure if one is allowed remix the MATLAB(r) logo in that way. After all, it's trademarked.

Comment: I think it would be rather unsettling to see such a cool show case - and the result has not been generated with the software at all. I believe it would be cool if the image would have been output of `matlab2tikz`.

Comment: I think I would like this even better if it said "LaTeX" instead of "TikZ" (to make immediately clear what it's used for for anyone who doesn't know TikZ), and if the image would be an output of matlab2tikz. Not sure how m2t does on the MATLAB logo actually...

Comment: @Nico m2t doesnot work on the last image. I haven't tried with the simpler image (without transparecy, hue etc) though. Can you pleaase run the matlab code above and see if you can modify m2t so that it converts? I don't like to simplify the image :)

Answer (score 30):

A more playful proposal

[image: TeX Lion plus MatLab wizardry!]

It's a pity TikZ does not have a mascot!

Comment: This has amused me quite exceptionally. Great idea! :-D

Answer (score 19):

Here is what I think about your wonderful contribution :)

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}    
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[font=\Huge\bfseries] 
        {\textbackslash\hspace{-1ex} \includegraphics[height=19pt,trim=0 150 0 0]{matlablogo};};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Matlab Logo is taken from [here](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Matlab_Logo.png) under the impression that it is CC license. But I'm pretty sure mathworks will try to deny that. So it's best to change a color tiny bit and change the view angle exactly 1 degrees such that it's not the official logo any more but a mathematical function that has nothing to do with mathworks.

Comment: I'm not a lawyer, but I think it'd be hard to get away with a 1-degree change in the view angle. That would mean that the smallest correction (e.g., changing one pixel) obliterates an entire design. We could possibly use the `membrane` plot though.

Comment: @Nico You never know. Depends on your lawyer :) Vairis' plot might save you anyhow with mesh lines.

Answer (score 12):

### Version 1

I tried something like this in MATLAB:

```
surf(membrane), view(-52,30), axis off
```

Plus my favorite package (thank you @Nico):

```
matlab2tikz(['C:\...\logo.tex'])
```

Put this line to add the text in the logo file (tikZ):

```
\path (9,5) node[left,scale=6,rotate=15]{\LaTeX};
```

Included it in a file with all the necessary preambules

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pstricks}
```

And came up with this:

[image: Possible idea for the logo]

Feel free to change stuff. Just wanted to add something to the community.

### Version 2

Made a draft version with `Sketch ->TeX` for the arm (default example + tweaks) and `MATLAB->TeX` for the logo.
[image: Another possible idea for the logo]

If interested, I can add all the parameters and code later.

Comment: If you need the complete files, let me know ;)

Comment: Hahaha great! it's like `matlab, Che cavolo dici?` gesture

Comment: @percusse your comment made my day

Comment: @percusse found this comment a year later, made my day again. After this post I am actually using this phrase here and there... So - lifechanging, I guess

Comment: Haha great. Fun is the cure to life !!

Answer (score 9):

Here's a simple logo:

[image]

It can be easily altered to fit a horizontal format or to have a dark background.

Answer (score 8):

This may also serve as a starting point for something fancier - I'm no designer and my creativity is not great in the graphical department.

[image: Proposed Logo]

Answer (score 5):

Fun contribution in the style of [David O'Reilly](http://www.davidoreilly.com/design/dumb-stuff/) from someone who wants to remain anonymous.

[image: m2t]

Comment: I think the very much speaks to the average MATLAB user. ;)

Comment: Comic Sans? Oh lord...

Comment: This must have been designed by MathWorks for OS X! ;-)