# Mathematica logo in LaTeX?

Tags: formatting, wolfram-mathematica, logos

Is there any command for inserting the Mathematica logo, in the same way Matlab's can be inserted with `\Matlab`?

Comment: There is a `\Matlab` command? `\textsc{Mathematica}`

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/156383/typesetting-programming-packages-libraries-in-latex

Comment: Are you referring to the [Matlab-style logo](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/132985/5764) as an image, or using plain text?

Comment: plain text. Not an image. I can't use an image in a resume.

Comment: I just tried \Matlab in one of my documents.  I was told undefined control sequence.  What packages has this ability?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minion_(typeface)#Usage), the Wolfram Mathematica Logo is typeset using the [Minion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minion_(typeface)) typeface. Hence you need the Minion font to typeset the logo without including an image.

Here is a version for `pdflatex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor}
\definecolor{Mathematica}{HTML}{ed192d}
\font\minionit=MinionPro-It-osf-t1
\font\minionup=MinionPro-Regular-osf-t1
\newcommand\Mathematica{%
    \textcolor{Mathematica}{\minionup Wolfram}
    {\minionit Mathematica}\textsuperscript{\resizebox{!}{0.4ex}{\textregistered}}%
    \resizebox{!}{1.6ex}{\textcolor{Mathematica}{\minionup 9}}%
}
\begin{document}
Foo \Mathematica\ Bar
\end{document}
```

> [image]

And here a version for `xelatex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{fontspec,graphicx,xcolor}
\definecolor{Mathematica}{HTML}{ed192d}
\newcommand\Mathematica{{\fontspec[Numbers=OldStyle]{Minion Pro}%
    \textcolor{Mathematica}{Wolfram}
    \textit{Mathematica}\textregistered%
    \resizebox{!}{1.6ex}{\textcolor{Mathematica}{9}}%
}}
\begin{document}
Foo \Mathematica\ Bar
\end{document}
```

> [image]

For reference, here a logo from the Wolfram homepgae

> [image]